# Ghost Errors Building C source code

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile this open source code library, http://sourceforge.net/projects/ballisticslib/files/

I get hundreds of errors, most of which are saying that values are undefined, etc.  The code has 1 header file and the source is split up amongst 7 c files which are all just methods.  Now I am not familiar with C and my plan has been to set this code library up as a compiled Library and import and wrap the functionality into C#.  Now I just don't know how to get rid of all these errors as a lot are saying that variables are not defined or missing semicolons when the line before the error saying the variable is not defined is the declaration of the variable.  The same is with the missing semicolon (its right there).

I've gone through the code and do not see any errors, does anyone know what I am doing wrong, its setup to not use pre compiled headers and I've been toggling through multiple settings in the properties of the project.

Also I created an empty C++ project and added all of the files, and this is in VS2010

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what the errors are?

Comment: I can post all 70, but they are multiples of the same thing.  There are 3 different ones,  Undeclared Identifier errors,  syntax error: missing ';' before 'type', then multiple intellisense errors about different identifiers being undefined.  Nothing useful out of that.  As I said those undeclared identifiers occur after the variable is declared eg. 

int s = 0;
for(s=0;s<=100;s++)
{
}
it says on the for loop that s is undefined.  So something else is causing errors.

Comment: There's a happy medium between posting 70 errors and 0 errors.  Perhaps post two or three, with the code they point to?  Also, in old-style C, all your declarations have to happen before anything else in a function.  What happens if you move your `int n=0` to the top of the function?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, it is set up in an unusual way. The _*.c files are actually included in ballistics.h. That means your project should only contain example.c, with the rest of the C files being included instead of compiled.

Comment: Ive done that, all of the _*.c files are now located in the External Dependencies folder within the Solution Explorer, including the ballistics.h, I get 27 errors now, simply M_PI is undeclared and the integer n is undeclared within the _solve.c file, yet right before the error occurs I can see that n was declared as an integer and set to 0.

Comment: @michael - M_PI seems like 3.1415926? And to the problem of the undeclared integer n, I guess there may be some semicolons missing. Just check the lines around where the compiler tells you.